# Retrieve a JsonArray that is nested in a changing JSON structure/hierarchy with GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a situation where I want to retrieve an array from JSON output. The array and its respective members never change. However, the hierarchy of the JSON output that contains the array does change periodically (beyond my control). I am struggling to figure out how to reliably extract the array without knowing the structure of the JSON hierarchy.

Example:
In JSON output #1 we have a bunch of objects with a sailors array nested snuggly in between:

```
{
"eat": "grub",
"drink": "rum",
"sailors": [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }
]
}
```

In JSON output #2 we have the same sailors array but its located in a different part of the hierarchy:

```
{
"eat": "grub",
"drink": "rum",
"boats": [
    {
        "name": "blackpearl"
    },
    {
        "name": "batavia",
        "crew": [
            {
                "name": "captain"
            },
            {
                "name": "deckswab",
                "anotherObject": {
                    "sailors": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "John",
                            "lastName": "Doe"
                        },
                        {
                            "firstName": "Anna",
                            "lastName": "Smith"
                        },
                        {
                            "firstName": "Peter",
                            "lastName": "Jones"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

In both cases I want to end up with a Gson JsonArray of the sailors array.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject root = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray sailors = root.get("sailors").getAsJsonArray();
```

The above code works fine for the JSON #1 output. I know that I can rewrite it for JSON output #2 by stringing together a bunch of get and getAsJsonObject/Array methods..

However, I’m not sure how to adapt it so that it will always find the array no matter where it is located in the hierarchy without have to re-write the code each time. This is important for me since the JSON output will likely change again the future and I would like my code to be a little bit more durable so that I do not have to re-write or update it whenever the JSON hierarchy changes again.

Please help!

Comment: If it will always be 'sailors' you may just search recursively for that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use recursion and do this manually (using org.json). You may also use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to read the tree from the JSON string.

You should have a `getSailorsArray(String json)` method that returns an array of all sailors.

To do this recursively, create methods to read a `JSONArray`, read a `JSONObject` and read a value. Each method will accept an object as argument. Check if the type of object is a `JSONArray` or a `JSONObject` or a value and call the appropriate recursive method. If it is an array, you may call the `getJsonObject` method in loop.

Put in your logic to check for the sailors key, and return the array when you encounter it. There, you have it!